# How to maintain numbering and labels inside of a tabular

Tags: tables, enumerate, linguistics, gb4e

I'm using gb4e in order to number examples in my paper. I want to be able to number a tabular as an example, and then have each line of the tabular be a, b, c, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\let\ipa=\textipa
\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \begin{tabular}{l l l r}

     \ipa{\;Gleg-a}&\ipa{\;Glega}&`sing. dies'&D:156\\
     \ipa{\;Gleg-dk}&\ipa{\;Glegatk} & `corpse' & D:156\\
     \ipa{Peww-a}&\ipa{Pewwa} & `freezes' & D:30\\
     \ipa{Peww-dk}&\ipa{Pewwatk} & `frozen' & D:30\\
     \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-a}& \ipa{ha:w'a} & `has breath' & D:163\\
     \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-dk}& \ipa{ha:witk} & `having (bad) breath' & D:163


\end{tabular}
\end{exe}
```

I want this to appear as:

> (1)
>
> a. first item(tab)second part(tab)gloss(tab)page number
>
> b. second item(tab)second part(tab)gloss(tab)page number
>
> c. third item(tab)second part(tab)gloss(tab)page number

but with the (1) on the left side of the whole thing, and with the tabs all being aligned.

Is there any way to do this?

Then i could potentially reference a line of my example using \label?

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please edit your post and make it a fully compilable (minimum working) example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))? It would be a fine starting point for the solvers.

Comment: I believe you want `\begin{tabular}[t]{lllr}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array}
\let\ipa=\textipa

\newcounter{example}[xnumi]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{(\alph{example})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@example}{\thexnumi-}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\refstepcounter{example}\theexample}l l l l r}
  \label{a} & \ipa{\;Gleg-a}&\ipa{\;Glega}&`sing. dies'&D:156\\
  \label{b} & \ipa{\;Gleg-dk}&\ipa{\;Glegatk} & `corpse' & D:156\\
  \label{c} & \ipa{Peww-a}&\ipa{Pewwa} & `freezes' & D:30\\
  \label{d} & \ipa{Peww-dk}&\ipa{Pewwatk} & `frozen' & D:30\\
  \label{e} & \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-a}& \ipa{ha:w'a} & `has breath' & D:163\\
  \label{f} & \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-dk}& \ipa{ha:witk} & `having (bad) breath' & D:163
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

Here's a reference: \ref{c}

\begin{exe}
\ex
  \begin{tabular}[t]{>{\refstepcounter{example}\theexample}l l l l r}
  \label{aa} & \ipa{\;Gleg-a}&\ipa{\;Glega}&`sing. dies'&D:156\\
  \label{bb} & \ipa{\;Gleg-dk}&\ipa{\;Glegatk} & `corpse' & D:156\\
  \label{cc} & \ipa{Peww-a}&\ipa{Pewwa} & `freezes' & D:30\\
  \label{dd} & \ipa{Peww-dk}&\ipa{Pewwatk} & `frozen' & D:30\\
  \label{ee} & \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-a}& \ipa{ha:w'a} & `has breath' & D:163\\
  \label{ff} & \ipa{ha:w\super i\super P-dk}& \ipa{ha:witk} & `having (bad) breath' & D:163
\end{tabular}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

In the first column you just specify the label for subsequent reference.

[image]